# how to read this json array in java

Tags: java, php, arrays, json, eclipse

i have a json array generated by this php:

```
$filtros=mysql_query("SELECT id_transporte FROM user_trans WHERE id_usuario =     '".$id_usuario ."'");
for($i=0; $i<=mysql_num_rows($filtros); $i++){  
$rs[]= mysql_fetch_array($filtros,MYSQL_ASSOC);
}
foreach($rs as $valor){
    if (is_array($valor)) {
        foreach($valor as $valor1){
            $reportes[]= mysql_query("
                SELECT * FROM transportes 
                WHERE id_transporte='".$valor1."'
                ORDER BY fecha_reporte DESC ");
                }
    }       
}
foreach($reportes as $valor){
    if($valor != false){
        for($i=0; $i<=mysql_num_rows($valor); $i++){
        $row[]= mysql_fetch_array($valor,MYSQL_ASSOC);
        }                           
    }       
}
print_r (json_encode($row));
```

which returns:

```
[{"id_report":"73","id_transport":"624","txt_report":"Report0"},

{"id_report":"46","id_transport":"624","txt_report":"Report1"},false,

{"id_report":"74","id_transport":"9999","txt_report":"Report2"},

{"id_report":"52","id_transport":"9999","txt_report":"Report3"},false]
```

well, i try to read that, but java only read until "false"...
that array are 2 arrays which joined and printed, so i try this:

```
$row1=str_replace ( "false" , '{"salto":1}' , $row );
    $row1[]=false;
    print_r (json_encode($row1));
```

that returns the sames but "" instead "false" and a "false" in the end
but java continues reading until now the ""
i use that for read json

```
if (jdata!=null && jdata.length() > 0){

JSONObject json_data = null;

try{                        

System.out.println( jdata.length() );//java there print all the array length ignoring the "false" o ""

for (int i=0; i < jdata.length(); i++){ 

reportsId[i]=jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_report");
transportId[i]=jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_transport");
txt_report[i]=jdata.getJSONObject(i).getString("txt_report");
System.out.println( " i= "+ i); 

}
}
}catch(Exception e3){}
```

so my question is how read this, or change some lines on php

Comment: There's a comma missing after "id_report":"46"

Comment: i edit the json for print here, is auto encode by php, thats ok, the problem is when read the "false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in your PHP you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and dangerous. Your code could be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/PDO)

You could probably make this much faster by running a single query that would also get rid of the false values. You certainly don't need to stuff everything into an array and then loop over it.

Here's my take:

```
$resp = mysql_query("SELECT t.* FROM transportes t 
    JOIN user_trans ut ON t.id_transporte=ut.id_transporte 
    WHERE ut.id_usuario='$id_usuario' 
    ORDER BY fecha_reporte DESC");

if(!$resp) {
    // handle the error!
    die(mysql_error())
}

$output = [];
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resp) ) {
    $output[] = $row;
}

print_r(json_encode($output));
```

This should solve your problem with false values because they are likely due to the second query not being checked for errors.

Comment: WOuldn't this stop at the first false?!

Comment: He's getting false because he's doing a second query in the loop. This removes the falses entirely by getting all the matching rows in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON in not well formed.

There's a comma missing after `"id_report":"46"`